DPY-4011: the database or network closed connection in FastAPI
Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 986, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1432, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 698, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\oracledb\connection.py", line 826, in rollback
    self._impl.rollback()
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thick/connection.pyx", line 735, in oracledb.thick_impl.ThickConnImpl.rollback
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 456, in oracledb.thick_impl._raise_from_odpi
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 446, in oracledb.thick_impl._raise_from_info
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection
DPI-1080: connection was closed by ORA-03113
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 2429127
Session ID: 11672 Serial number: 46066
Help:
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-03113/A==))

def get_connection_to_oracle_db():
        
    engine = create_engine(
    f'oracle+oracledb://{O_USER}:{O_PASSWORD}@{O_HOST}:{O_PORT}/?service_name={O_DB}',
    pool_size=10,              
    max_overflow=20,            
    pool_timeout=60,           
    pool_recycle=300,
    thick_mode=thick_mode,    
    pool_pre_ping=True          
    )
    return engine
    
    
oracle_engine = get_connection_to_oracle_db()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=oracle_engine)

I use sqlalchemy to establish oracle connection to get data from oracle database in a FastAPI application.I established the connection in thick mode. Most of the Time my connection is perfect and I get data perfectly without any error.Sometimes I get the above mentioned error and this makes my API to freeze completely which doesnt allow to use other services.
Can anyone help me with this.

ORA-03113 is a generic client-side error that is raised when a network connection is ended unexpectedly. The cause for the disconnect could be almost anything, and is likely in your network or on your server, not in your code or on your client. You will need the assistance of a network admin and/or database admin to get to the root cause.

Overall behavior re freezing when the database (or net) drops the connection could be improved if you moved to use the Oracle connection pool. This will also give you Oracle availability (such as transparent reconnection when a connection dies) and high-availability features (such as the ability to use Application Continuity), and will let you use DRCP if you decide you need that:
See https://github.com/cjbj/python-oracledb-demos-2022/blob/main/6_sqlalchemy_example.py#L32-L36
# SQLAlchemy 2.0

import os, platform
import getpass
import oracledb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool


ld = None  # On Linux, pass None
if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
    ld = str(os.environ.get('HOME'))+'/Downloads/instantclient_23_3'
elif platform.system() == 'Windows':
    ld = r'C:\oracle\instantclient_19_23'
oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=ld)

un = os.environ.get('PYO_SAMPLES_ADMIN_USER')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')
pw = getpass.getpass(f'Enter password for {un}@{cs}: ')

pool = oracledb.create_pool(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs, min=4, max=4, increment=0)
engine = create_engine("oracle+oracledb://", creator=pool.acquire, poolclass=NullPool)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    print(connection.scalar(text("""SELECT UNIQUE CLIENT_DRIVER
                                    FROM V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO
                                    WHERE SID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID')""")))

